# How to use thevenin theorem in this example?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Use thevenin theorem to find the current through 2 ohm resistor also find thevenin voltage and thevenin resistence.]
Use thevenin theorem to find the current through 2 ohm resistor also find thevenin voltage and thevenin resistence.

My approach:First I open circuited the resistance through 2 ohm resistor then used voltage division to find the thevenin voltage but got the wrong answer.
My calculations:
Vth = 9V * ((6+4)/(4+4+6))= 6.43V.

But the Thevenin voltage in answer is 2.571 volts.

Comment: You need to show your calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the load, you end up with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe0ULx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It follows that \$I_y=0\$ since it is an open circuit.

$$I_x=\dfrac{9\text{V}}{4\Omega+4\Omega+6\Omega}=0.643\text{A}$$

The potential difference between the terminals A and B is the \$V_{\text{TH}}\$. This is just the voltage across the farthest to the right \$4\Omega\$ resistor.

Then

$$V_{oc}=V_{\text{TH}}=(0.643\text{A})(4\Omega)=2.57\text{V} $$

You need to find \$R_{\text{TH}}\$. Short circuit the 9V voltage source and find the equivalent resistance at the A and B terminals. That would be:

$$ R_{\text{TH}}=((4\Omega+6\Omega)||4\Omega)+5\Omega=7.86\Omega$$

With that, you can find \$I_2\$.

Comment: Learned a new way by this procedure,absoluetly correct.

Answer (score 0):

The current through the \$5\Omega\$ resistor is the same as through the \$2\Omega\$ resistor so you can combine them into a single \$7\Omega\$.

That new resistor is in parallel with a \$4\Omega\$ resistor. You can combine them again into a \$2.54\Omega\$ resistor. So you end up with \$12.54\Omega\$ total resistance across the voltage source.

You can also use that to find the voltage across the imaginary \$2.54\Omega\$ resistor.

$$9*\frac{6.54}{12.54} - 9*\frac{4}{12.54} = 1.82 V$$

Then you can use current splitting to find how much current flows through the \$7\Omega\$ resistor using \$I = \frac VR\$

Comment: We have to use thevenin theorem.