# Finding current through thevenin theorem

Tags: voltage

Find the current through 20 ohms using thevenin theorem.

[image]!

I am unable to apply thevenin  theorem on this circuit. Can somebody give me hint on how to simplify this..

I first short circuit the 20 ohms and then used kvl to find the current through the three branches.

Equation: 45-120-5(I2+I3) -10(I1+I3) =0

I1 is current in left branch, I2 in right and I3 in bottom.

10(I1+I3) +5(I2+I3) +5(I3) =20

I can't seem to find the third equation.. Can someone help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question not demonstrating the own approach or at least effort made by the poster.

Comment: Learn to spell the theorem name first.

Comment: Why are you shorting the 20 ohms?

Comment: @Scáthach That is a different situation and question. Your question is solved in any of at least three different ways, none of which involves shorting out the 20 Ohm resistor.

Answer (score 3):

Below, I've redrawn the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRzMPX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's exactly the same as the one you have drawn out. I just picked one of the shared nodes to be ground and worked from there.

Does this help you analyze the circuit? Using nodal analysis, this isn't too hard.

But you can also use mesh analysis -- perhaps easier for you in this case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fepMRP.png)</sup>

Here, you'd solve for three currents using three easily developed equations and then find the difference between \$I_1\$ and \$I_3\$ to work out the current in the \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor.

---

Given your comments now about ***how*** you are supposed to solve this, look at the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD0zQu.png)</sup>

Here, I've removed the \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor from the circuit and, in its place, provided nodes \$A\$ and \$B\$ where it used to be. (I've decided to ground the left side.) You should be able to work out the Thevenin equivalent at node \$A\$, now. (\$B\$ is ground.) Once you have \$V_\text{TH}\$ and \$R_\text{TH}\$, you can then re-insert the \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor and work out the current in it.

Comment: Why is 10 ohms not shorted

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/314787/how-to-use-thevenin-theorem-in-this-example

Comment: @Scáthach Why would it be? That's something I didn't understand about your question.

Comment: Shouldn't we ignore 10 ohms like the method is done I the linked  post( actually I was supposed to calculate current through 20 ohms hence the confusion but let's go with 10 ohms) .

Comment: @Scáthach No. I think your situation is resolved as I've indicated and that you misunderstand your link.

Comment: @Scáthach If you really wanted to make the solution harder, you could remove the 10 Ohm resistor and solve the rest of the circuit for its Thevenin equivalent at the two nodes at either end of it and then find the current by adding it back in. But that's not nearly so easy. Are you bent on solving it that way? (And you wouldn't short it, you'd remove or open it.)

Comment: The question is telling me to solve it that way so I think I am supposed to go through the method as given in that post but I am having trouble applying it..

Comment: @Scáthach Are you supposed to short that resistor? Seriously? I don't think I can help you, then. Opening it can work. But I don't think I can help if you are supposed to short it.

Comment: No I think I am supposed to find the thevenin equivalent like u have suggested like I am supposed to remove it

Comment: @Scáthach That will work. Remove it, then ground one of the two ends and solve the Thevenin equivalent for the other node. This will provide a voltage and a resistance. Then insert the 10 Ohm resistor and work out the current.

Comment: @Scáthach I've added another section. This is about as far as I want to go, though. You should be able to work it out from here.